# Parse.com - Email Verification and adding a new object with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, email-verification

I have got my Parse.com login view controller and sign up view controller working just fine but I would like to do email verification. So when the user has verified through email, they can enter the app but if not, they are denied access.

Also, I would like another text field where the user enters details for a special code, it's like the secondary password I guess, this will also have to be entered into the sign up screen when they sign up to the app.

Other than that, I can register users and get them to log in, I just need help with this.

Comment: Your question isn't very specific. You should show your code for the config of the register controller (have you tried adding a field) and for the signup (have you tried editing the user). The parse website also offers all code samples in swift with buttons at the bottom of each sample.

Comment: on Parse in your apps settings go to the email section and turn on "Verify User Emails".  Then you can check the value of the emailVerfied column in the user table when they try to login

Comment: Let me get my question a bit better, I want to make it so that when you sign up, you sign up with almost like a secondary password. Then when you go to log in, your data will be linked with that secondary password. Also parse does not give any code for editing the login screen, if i have missed it please redirect me, thank-you @Wain

Comment: https://www.parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views